# Do not wake up from suspended state when unfolding laptop

Tags: suspend, standby

My suspended Ubuntu/Linux Mint laptop automatically wakes up from stand-by when unfolding.

I'd rather have it to wait for me manually pressing the power button.

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu/Linux Mint"?

Comment: To do this I think you can use the power button to suspend laptop and then close lid.

Comment: @DKBose Ubuntu and Linux Mint are technically closely identical.

Answer (score 0):

When your laptop is already on and you press the power button a pop-up menu appears:

[image]

- Select **Suspend** (the second pop-up menu option).
- You can also select **Suspend** from the top right **Gear** menu.
- Your laptop suspends and then you can close the lid.
- When you open your laptop lid it does NOT resume.
- You need to press the power button to resume.